# Regarding the implementation of typescript as to how it fits into a project

Tags: typescript

I need to know how a typescript code is implemented in a project in asp.net mvc, what is its role and how its linked in a view and how it retrieves data from the model to the view

Comment: How much do you know about software development?

Answer (score 3):

It has the same role as JavaScript. Your typescript code gets compiled down to javascript, and that is used as it has always been used.

Comment: This is probably a more open-minded response than my comment. I will try to do better with this. Thanks for the answer, @bassarat.

Comment: Actually your response was valid. Its a comment anyways.i actually feel bad for swooping in for easy points :)